# Contar registros diferentes a un campo predeterminado sql php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en donde me cuente los registros diferentes a uno predeterminado.

Ejemplo
tengo una tabla que tiene 42 registros para ADMINISTRACIÓN y 52 registros para CONTABILIDAD, pero muchos otros como NO INFORMO o SE RETIRA entre otros más

quiero que la consulta solo me cuente los que son diferentes a ADMINISTRACIÓN y CONTABILIDAD

Si alguien me puede orientar, ya que no sé qué función realizar en la consulta.
Gracias

```
<div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="card info-card customers-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Alumnos solicitaron </br> Administracion</h5>

                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="ps-3">
                      <h4><?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM especialidades_2024 WHERE especialidad = 'ADMINISTRACION' AND estado ='1'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            $numero = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                            echo '' . $numero . '';
                            ?></h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="card info-card customers-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Alumnos solicitaron </br> Contabilidad</h5>

                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="ps-3">
                      <h4><?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM especialidades_2024 WHERE especialidad = 'CONTABILIDAD' AND estado ='1'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            $numero = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                            echo '' . $numero . '';
                            ?></h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tienes que usar `NOT IN (..., ...)`, `COUNT(1)` y `GROUP BY ...`. Si compartes la definición de las tablas podremos darte una consulta más detallada.

Comment: Acabo de añadir las consultas que me cuentan las especialidades de ADMINISTRACIÓN y CONTABILIADAD para la pregunta mensionada no tengo idea

Comment: Solucionado. 
$query = "SELECT especialidad FROM especialidades_2024 WHERE especialidad NOT IN ('ADMINISTRACION', 'CONTABILIDAD');";